# How do I find my answers or anything I wrote here?

Tags: support

How do I find my answers to questions? I see no way to search for them or anything I wrote. And, why do I have to even ask this question?

Comment: One asks questions because you seek answers. Given that the working of the SE network is not encoded in your DNA, some learning process is inevitable. And learning to search is a trait that should be gleefully sought after. (This comment was to gently remind you that your frustration was coming through in your post, which does not add to its utility at all.)

Answer (score 4):

Just go to your profile and click on `answers`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your profile contains a wealth of information about your activity on the site, including specific breakdowns of your questions, answers, and - under `all actions` - your edits, comments, reviews, and more.

For more details, the [search tool](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=) on the site is relatively sophisticated if you know how to use it, and it has a handy guide accessible by clicking the `Advanced Search Tips` link on the right sidebar. Some notables are

- `user:me` to search for your own posts (or e.g. `user:50583` to search for, say, ACuriousMind's posts, since their user id (the number in the url of their profile) is 50583)
- `is:question` and `is:answer` to limit the search to just questions or just answers
- flags for `closed`, `deleted`, `migrated`
- and a whole host of others.

You can also perform specific searches subject to those constraints, and order them using the tabs just below the search bar on the results page.